# Two color gradient in Powerpoint macro/ second color stays white

Tags: vba, gradient, powerpoint

Trying to create a 2 color gradient in a powerpoint macro. The second color keeps showing up as white. I saw another question on here about the same problem but the answer didn't work for me. Can anyone spot my issue? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape

Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

'TIMELINE BOX
    Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=-5, Top:=0, Width:=365, Height:=50)

    'Shape Name
        Shp.Name = "DateBox1"
    'No Shape Border
        Shp.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        Shp.Line.Weight = 2
        Shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'Shape Fill Color
        Shp.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(18, 115, 57)
        Shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(72, 166, 105)
        Shp.Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
        'Shp.Fill.GradientStops.Item(1).Position = 50
        Shp.Fill.RotateWithObject = msoTrue

    'Shape Text Color
        Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'Text inside Shape
        Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "DATE"
    'Center Align Text
        Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
    'Vertically Align Text to Middle
        Shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    'Adjust Font Size
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 22
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Myriad Pro"
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.Type = msoShadow1
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.OffsetX = 10
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.OffsetY = 10
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.Size = 1
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.Blur = 4
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.Transparency = 0.5
        Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Shadow.Visible = True
  'Shadow
    Shp.Shadow.Type = msoShadow1
    Shp.Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Shp.Shadow.Transparency = 0.7
    Shp.Shadow.OffsetX = 2
    Shp.Shadow.OffsetY = 2
    Shp.Shadow.Blur = 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the gradient fill first, then set the colors:

```
Shp.Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(18, 115, 57)
Shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(72, 166, 105)
```